# Ubuntu 18.04 Both Drives hang at boot on raid

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, hard-drive, raid

I am having booting issues with Ubuntu on 2 hard drives.
I built this rig with Nvidia i6800 motherboard, and 2 HDs, 
The reason for 2 drives is one is the main and the other is a backup.

GRUB BOOTS

```
Main SATA:  ST2000DMOOB-2FR102

Backup SATA: WDC WD20EZAZ-00GGJB0
```

With 2 memory slots gone bad out of the 4 on that i6800 MB, I decided to change out the motherboard.
And I did to a: Intel DQ77MK Quad Core i5 3470 3.2GHz 8GB DDR3 Motherboard CPU RAM Combo - 14381

Now with better hardware Ubuntu on both drives is running great!
The problem is booting, both drives hang here:

```
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [    4.399682] sd 3: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [    4.439785]  sdb: sdb1
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [    4.448272] sd 3: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [    4.677222] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [   93.650765] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 14885 MB/s
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [   93.714763] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 10192 MB/s
Jan  4 17:47:39  kernel: [   93.770764] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 12508 MB/s
```

Between , ata6: SATA and raid6, is 1.4 minutes. is there a way to see what happening?

```
Jan  3 23:02:40  kernel: [    2.595791] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jan  3 23:02:40  kernel: [   92.398272] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

This time at ata6: SATA and EXT4, 1.5 minutes, I'm very curious what is causing this delay.

I have no idea what the problem is, yet google searching has led me to a lot.
There is no floppy disc option in the bios.

Really like to get this fix, it takes some time to boot.
Thanks for you help.

Using the command:

```
nano /etc/fstab

Main Boot Drive  /etc/fstab
 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3ba4b7d5-9192-43b6-a2b8-955b8eb4ed7c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

2nd Boot Drive
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3bbd0470-d6a3-48e8-8884-e5b2d28fcd00 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I know the errors are setting drives to read only and that's ok, but why is it taking so long to boot?

So it seems there is a mounting problem, like I said, this is over my head, and I'm learning more everyday.
A fix for this would be great!
I no longer get the ubuntu loading screen, not sure why?

Thanks for the help.

```
dmesg | grep SATA

$ dmesg | grep SATA
[    1.105157] ahci 00000:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x2d impl SATA mode
[    1.143179] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf6336000 port 0xf6336100 irq 26
[    1.143379] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf6336000 port 0xf6336200 irq 26
[    1.143496] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf6336000 port 0xf6336280 irq 26
[    1.143693] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf6336000 port 0xf6336380 irq 26
[    1.451472] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.851525] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.163558] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.483549] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
```

*******UPDATE*******

I was planning on using the bios to set which drive to boot from but GRUB jumps in and seems to ruin my plans.

Now if I lose the main drive, I cannot boot from the backup drive, I need to fix that. Hopefully I can!
The Ubuntu install on both drives is default from file system to swap to ect...
It appears only the main drive boots, there is a boot.log file there but, no info in the boot.log file on the back up drive, just a blank empty file.
There are files for the kernel.log and system with info in them on the backup drive.

"No btrfs" with both drives using ext4 I see no need for that system.
So I will remove it, since it is not needed.

"No swap partition (this will effect hibernation)", this seems to compensate for lack of memory no problem there, I have 8g of memory  was planning on going to 32 if needed.

"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"

I moded that line already with,

"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Now i can see the drive booting.

"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noresume"

Is that the way I should edit that line in that file?
 I want to keep seeing the booting on screen.

open(or create) /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.conf
replace(or add) RESUME=UUID=xxx with RESUME=noneissue

That folder conf.d is empty on both drives.
No problem creating a file.
How do I find the "UUID" and if there is two, which one should I use?

Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 0):

The booting issue was because of Ubuntu.
I upgraded to 20.04 and it screams blazing fast at boot now!
The problem was Ubuntu.